# Retrieving data from a form?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to enter data to a website using python, search for it and then extract the address, but not sure where to proceed after this. My code as of now looks like this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("https://www.matsugov.us/myproperty")
for form in br.forms():
     print "Form name:", form.name
     print form
```

This gives me the formname and the form. The form has multiple fields under drop down and I need to select Tax ID search and fetch the value '218N02W27C003' and then should display the result. Out of this result we just need to take the parcel address and display the output.

Comment: @martineau I am sorry that formatting didn't go well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know the ***name*** of form, form name can be selected using

```
for form in br.forms():
        if form.attrs.get('name') == 'frmSearch':
            br.form = form
            break
```

To select a option from drop down menu, pass the ***value*** of option as a list

`br.form['ddlType']=["taxid"]`

**overall code:**

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("https://www.matsugov.us/myproperty")

for form in br.forms():
    if form.attrs.get('name') == 'frmSearch':
        br.form = form
        break

br.form['ddlType']=["taxid"]
br['txtParm']="abcdef"
req=br.submit().read()
print req
```

for reference HTML code was something like this.

```
<select name="ddlType" id="ddlType">
    <option value="owner">Owner Search</option>
    <option value="buyer">Buyer Search</option>
    <option value="address">Address Search</option>
    <option value="subdivision">Subdivision Search</option>
    <option value="subdivision2">Subdivision ID Search</option>
    <option value="taxid">Tax ID Search</option>
    <option value="parcel">Parcel ID Search</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankush.
For taxid 218N02W27C003The output comes but has lot of junk values. I need just the address from that. Any clues how can I filter that? Few lines of o/p are "</td><td class="Grid_5">2092  N PITTMAN                   RD         </td><td class="Grid_4">                              </td><td class="Grid_1 icon">"
I just need  "N PITTMAN                   RD"  out of this

Comment: were you able to find something?